# I'm having problems performing sentiment analysis on R using a JSON file

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I have the the following [JSON file](https://core.ac.uk/api-v2/articles/search/cells?page=1&pageSize=20&metadata=true&fulltext=false&citations=false&similar=false&duplicate=false&urls=true&faithfulMetadata=false&apiKey=PykSKLeJz7ZldYQbNWoTDvwCfnarFXOg) and I want to do a sentiment analysis on the "descriptions" keys in the JSON file.I'm using this [tutorial](http://tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html) for help. Below is the code I have so far:

```
library(jsonlite)      #formats the json file into an appropriate R structure 
formatdata<- fromJSON("the json file", flatten = TRUE)
View(formatdata)
text <- c(formatdata)
library(dplyr)
text_df<-data_frame(line =1:20, text=text)
library(tidytext)
text_df %>%
      unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

A portion of the "formatdata" variable looks like this :

```
[1] "The complex interplay between cancer cells, stromal cells and immune cells in the tumor microenvironment (TME) regulates tumorigenesis and provides emerging targets for immunotherapies. Crosstalk between CD4(+) T cells and proliferating chronic lymphocytic leukemia (CLL) tumor B cells occurs within lymphoid tissue pseudo-follicles and investigating these interactions is essential to understand both disease pathogenesis and the effects of immunotherapy. Tumor-derived extracellular vesicle (EV) shedding is emerging as an important mode of intercellular communication in the TME. In order to characterize tumor EVs released in response to T cell-derived TME signals, we performed microRNA (miR) profiling of EVs released from CLL cells stimulated with CD40 and IL-4. Our results reveal an enrichment of specific cellular miRNAs including miR-363 within EVs derived from CD40/IL-4 stimulated CLL cells compared to parental cell miRNA content and control EVs from unstimulated CLL cells. We demonstrate that autologous patient CD4(+) T cells internalize CLL-EVs containing miR-363 that targets the immunomodulatory molecule CD69. We further reveal that autologous CD4(+) T cells that are exposed to EVs from CD40/IL-4 stimulated CLL cells exhibit enhanced migration, immunological synapse signaling and interactions with tumor cells. Knockdown of miR-363 in CLL cells prior to CD40/IL-4 stimulation, prevented the ability of CLL-EVs to induce increased synapse signaling and confer altered functional properties to CD4(+) T cells. Taken together, these data reveal a novel role for CLL-EVs in modifying T cell function that highlights unanticipated complexity of intercellular communication that may have implications for bidirectional CD4(+) T-cell:tumor interactions within the TME.Peer-reviewedPost-prin"                          
 [2] "Objective: Gut homing of lymphocytes via adhesion molecules has recently emerged as new target for therapy in inflammatory bowel diseases. We aimed to analyze the in vivo homing of effector (Teff) and regulatory (Treg) T cells to the inflamed gut via α4β7 and GPR15. Design: We assessed the expression of homing receptors on T cells in peripheral blood and inflamed mucosa. We studied the migration pattern and homing of Teff and Treg cells to the inflamed gut using intravital confocal microscopy and FACS in a humanized mouse model in DSS-treated NSG (NOD.Cg-Prkdcscid-Il2rgtm1Wjl/SzJ) mice. Results: Expression of GPR15 and α4β7 was significantly increased on Treg rather than Teff cells in peripheral blood of patients with ulcerative colitis (UC) as compared to Crohn´s disease and controls. In vivo analysis in a humanized mouse model showed augmented gut homing of UC Treg cells as compared to controls. Moreover, suppression of UC (but not control) Teff and Treg cell homing was noted upon treatment with the α4β7 antibody vedolizumab. In contrast, siRNA blockade of GPR15 had only effects on homing of Teff cells but did not affect Treg homing in UC. Clinical vedolizumab treatment was associated with marked expansion of UC Treg cells in peripheral blood. Conclusion: α4β7 rather than GPR15 is crucial for increased colonic homing of UC Treg cells in vivo, while both receptors control UC Teff homing. Vedolizumab treatment impairs homing of UC Treg cells leading to their accumulation in peripheral blood with subsequent suppression of systemic effector T cell expansion"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [3] "This work was financially supported by the “Deutsches Zentrum für Luft- und Raumfahrt e.V.” (DLR) under the project “Solarzellenkonzepte für Raumfahrtgeneratoren der nächsten Generation” (SoNG, Contract No. 50RN1301). S.H. gratefully acknowledges the support by the Royal Society and the Wolfson Foundation.Dilute nitride GaInN(Sb)As with a band gap (Eg) of 1.0 eV is a promising material for the integration in next generation multijunction solar cells. We have investigated the effect of a compositionally graded GaInNAs absorber layer on the spectral response of a GaInNAs sub cell. We produced band gap gradings (ΔEg) of up to 39 meV across a 1 μm thick GaInNAs layer. Thereby, the external quantum efficiency—compared to reference cells—was increased due to the improved extraction of photo-generated carriers from 34.0% to 36.7% for the wavelength range from 900 nm to 1150 nm. However, this device figure improvement is accompanied by a small decrease in the open circuit voltage of about 20 mV and the shift of the absorption edge to shorter wavelengths.Publisher PDFPeer reviewe"
```

What I want to do is using the "nrc" or "bing" lexicon to do sentiment analysis. But when I try using the code below, this error appears:

```
text_df %>%
+     inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"))
Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try combining the strings inside formatdata together and see if it works